# What is the impact of climate change on tropospheric ozone production and vice versa?

Tags: climate, climate-change, air-pollution, ozone

I know ground ozone reduce the photosynthesis rate of vegetation and could lead to increase respiration and hence more CO2 in the atmosphere, contributing to global warming. But what is the opposite? How is climate change affect the production of ozone? Higher temperature means higher ozone production? but also more water vapour in the atmosphere which counteract it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since ozone is a greenhouse gas, I would say it would enhance warming.

[This article](http://journals.ametsoc.org/doi/abs/10.1175/JCLI-D-12-00168.1) explains how regional climate may be impacted by ozone

[This article](http://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/10.1029/2005JD006852/full) says that while global ozone should decrease as a result of warming, ozone over populated areas should increase.

Water vapor plays a minute role in the production of tropospheric ozone- it increases the amount of hydroxyl radical to be used in hydroperoxyl formation.